# Get the cursor associated with the contact table whose image is not filled

Tags: android, android-cursorloader

I am trying to get a cursor containing the names of contacts that do not have an birthday in Android (in **ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Event.START_DATE** with 
**ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Event.TYPE = ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Event.TYPE_BIRTHDAY**)

I go through a CursorLoader for a display on my listview. But I do not really know what condition indicated for the *selection* in

```
new CursorLoader(
                getActivity(),
                ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI,
                {
                  ContactsContract.Contacts._ID,
                  ContactsContract.Contacts.LOOKUP_KEY,
                  ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME_PRIMARY
                },
                ???,
                null,
                null);
```

Can you help me ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution but that does not pass through a selection of query. Because the **ContentProvider of the Contacts is not explicitly linked to birthdays** (this is why we go through a CommonDataKinds)

I have bypassed the problem by doing a filter on the retrieve object in the cursor. So of course it's less optimized than if it was a query condition but it works.